# Ruby's "all?" method has an order or it's random?

Tags: ruby

My question is about the `all?` method in ruby. Please consider the following code:

```
validations = [:check1,:check2,:check2]
validations.all? do |n|
  send(n)
end
```

Does it evaluate the collection in a specific order every time (`:check1`, `:check2`, and go on), or is this random order?

Comment: Your question about `any?` or `all?`?

Comment: @johnnyRose Don't change the question.

Comment: sorry for the typo, Fixed. I am asking about `all?` but it would be good to know about `any?` as well.

Comment: Since `any?`'s receiver is an array, you are speaking of [Array#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-any-3F). There's also the method [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), which can be used by instances of any class for which `any?` is not defined that `include`'s the module `Enumerable`. In some cases order is not defined for `any?`'s receiver. An example are instances of the class `Set`.

Comment: @jonnyRose, next time  please leave a comment when you think the OP has intended to ask a different question. Curioius, you've been around SO long enough to know that you need to be circumspect about changing your question after answers have been posted, and if you do, you need to make it clear what you are doing by leaving the original question intact and clarifying with something like "Edit: ....", else you can render comments and answers non-sensical, as here. One downvote is mine.

Comment: My mistake, but when "any" is listed multiple times, and "all" is only mentioned once, I assumed it was obvious. After the question was fixed, it was clearly about "all", but I think I made a fairly reasonable judgement call with my initial edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it evaluates the condition block in the order of the elements in the array. When there is an element that returns a falsy value against the block, iteration stops at that element, and the block will not be evaluated against further elements. So when the code in the block has side effect, the order of the elements in the array does have consequence.

Comment: This is not true for `any?`.  It checks until any element condition is true or truthy.

Comment: @vgoff The question had been inappropriately changed by johnnyRose. I reverted it.

Comment: His words are "any?" his code is "all?" so it appears he is asking of both, your answer is true for both, if the inverse is applied, of course.  Confusing question still.

Answer (score 4):

Semantically, there is no need for it to preserve any particular order. All it needs to know is whether the block evaluates to a falsy value for at least one element. For that, order is irrelevant.

However, all `Enumerable` methods rely on `each` and on `each` alone, so pragmatically, we can assume that `all?`'s ordering guarantees are the same as `each`'s. Note, however, that `all?` is lazy, it will not evaluate more than it has to. (This contradicts the documentation which states that each element of the collection is passed to the block.)

Not all of this is guaranteed, however, by the [Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579), the [YARV testsuite](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/ruby/test_enum.rb#L236-243), or the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F).

Specifically, this is what section 15.3.2.2.1 of the ISO Ruby Language Specification has to say:

> ## 15.3.2.2.1 `Enumerable#all?`
>
> `all?`(*&block*)
>
> ### Visibility: public
>
> ### Behavior:
>
> 1. Invoke the method `each` on the receiver.
> 2. For each element X which the method `each` yields:
>
>    1. If *block* is given, call *block* with X as the argument. If this call results in a falseish object, return `false`.
>    2. If *block* is not given, and X is a falseish object, return `false`.
> 3. Return `true`.

So, it *does* specify that not necessarily all elements will be `yield`ed, but it does not specify any particular order.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction there. It's just implying that a return of the result may occur in the middle of `each` and may effectively interrupt enumeration. Each element that `each` would have yielded up to that point would indeed be evaluated. Regardless, +1. Never expected a quote from Ruby spec for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
validations = [:check1,:check2,:check2]

validations.all? do |n|
      puts n
end
```

It prints the array in method's order.

Comment: **Nope.** It prints only `check1`. I understand your intention to cause a side-effect, but `puts` returns `nil`, that halts `all?`.